# Can I set a keyboard shortcut for Edit Symbol?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, shortcuts

I'd like to be able to set a hotkey that enters edit mode for the currently selected symbol. I checked in the shortcuts menu but couldn't see it there. Is it possible to create a shortcut for the *Edit Symbol* command?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience you cannot create a shortcut for the edit symbol.  You can view the symbols in the `Symbols Panel` by going to `Window > Symbol` and double clicking on any symbol there to edit:

[image]

[image]

You could always review the Adobe's documentation for [scripting](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html) and see if you could develop a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

**You can double click a symbol that you've placed in the document.**

- To close it, you can double click outside the symbol or press esc key
- It works just about the same as double clicking a group or a mask.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I disabled double clicking because I found I would exit isolation mode when I didn't want to. I was hoping to replace all the double clicking functionality with keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @Ben, how did you disable double clicking?